# SQL join two tables by exact combination in common column

Tags: sql

I am trying to match two tables that have two columns; one with id number the other with type number.

In the first table id number can have different type numbers for example id 1 can have assigned type 1,2,3,4 in the second table id 1 can have assigned type 1,2,4 ... I would like to join the tables by id only if types are exactly the same ...

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Please include more information!

Comment: Add information about column data type , what is column properties and realationship? What is expected result? what have tried so far.

Comment: Please explain what the issue is. What does your data look like? What does your expected data look like? What did you try? Why is what you are doing not the right solution?

Comment: Perhaps the OP is still editing the question...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit, you need an INNER JOIN based on the combination of id and type in both tables:

```
SELECT
   Table1.id
   , Table1.type
   , Table1.ColumnsYouNeed
   , Table2.ColumnsYouNeed
FROM
    Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id 
        AND Table1.type = Table2.type
```

This would ensure that you only see those rows from both tables where the ID and Types match.

Example: 
If Table1 contains id = 12345 and type = 'foo', and Table2 has id = 12345 and type = 'foo', you will see the data (based on the respective columns you add to the `SELECT` statement) from both Table1 and Table2.

If Table1 contains id = 12345 and type = 'foo', but Table2 has id = 12345 and only type = 'bar', you will not see either rows.

Should you want to see all values in Table1, regardless of whether they are match in Table2, change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. Should you want to show all 
values from Table2, regardless of whether or not they exist in Table1, you could change `INNER JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`.

*** UPDATE based on your comment ***

I figured I'd show some additional examples of how `JOINs` work.

Let's start by setting up some sample tables with sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 (id tinyint, myType tinyint, columnA varchar(5));

INSERT INTO #table1 
VALUES (1, 1, 'aaaa'), (1, 2, 'aaab'), (1, 4, 'aaaac'), (2, 1, 'bbbbb'), (2,2, 'bbbbc'), (3, 1, 'dddd');

CREATE TABLE #table2 (id tinyint, myType tinyint, columnB varchar(25));

INSERT INTO #table2
VALUES (1, 1, 'Match for id 1'), (1, 2, 'Second match for id 1'), (1, 4, 'Match for id 1'), (2, 1, 'Match for id 2'), (2,3, 'Not a match for id 2'),  (4, 1, 'fdvg');
```

As you can see, all entries for id 1 exist in both tables. For id 2, #Table1 and #table2 both have type = 1, but type 2 and 3 only exist in one table (and thus should not show up in the final result). Id 3 only exists in #table1, and thus also won't show up. Id 4 only exists in #table2, and thus also shouldn't show.

Let's start by just joining the tables on id, without taking types into consideration:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM #table1
    JOIN #table2 ON #table1.id = #table2.id;
```

Result:

```
id  myType  columnA id  myType  columnB
1   1   aaaa    1   1   Match for id 1
1   2   aaab    1   1   Match for id 1
1   4   aaaac   1   1   Match for id 1
1   1   aaaa    1   2   Second match for id 1
1   2   aaab    1   2   Second match for id 1
1   4   aaaac   1   2   Second match for id 1
1   1   aaaa    1   4   Match for id 1
1   2   aaab    1   4   Match for id 1
1   4   aaaac   1   4   Match for id 1
2   1   bbbbb   2   1   Match for id 2
2   2   bbbbc   2   1   Match for id 2
2   1   bbbbb   2   3   Not a match for id 2
2   2   bbbbc   2   3   Not a match for id 2
```

As you can see, this will return a list of every row for which the ids exist in both tables, not taking types into account. This results in a result set where the combination of types are split out across rows. This is clearly not what we are after.

Next step is to add the types, and only return those rows where both the id and type exist in both tables:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM #table1
    JOIN #table2 ON #table1.id = #table2.id
        AND #table1.myType = #table2.myType;
```

Result:

```
id  myType  columnA id  myType  columnB
1   1   aaaa    1   1   Match for id 1
1   2   aaab    1   2   Second match for id 1
1   4   aaaac   1   4   Match for id 1
2   1   bbbbb   2   1   Match for id 2
```

Much better. Now we have a list of every combination that exists in both tables. However, as per your description, you do not want to see id = 2, because there's no full match on the types between the tables.

The above query already weeds out any rows existing in #table1 that do not exist in #table2 (id = 2, type = 2 is not returned), but obviously it did not take into account there is a row for in #table2 that does not exist in #table1.

We can accomplish that by adding a subquery listing all ids for which an entry in #table2 exists that does not exist in #table1:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM #table1
    JOIN #table2 ON #table1.id = #table2.id
        AND #table1.myType = #table2.myType
WHERE #table1.id NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT #Table2.id FROM #Table2 
                LEFT JOIN #table1 ON #table2.id = #table1.id 
                    AND #Table2.myType = #table1.myType
            WHERE #table1.MyType IS NULL
        );
```

Result:

```
1   1   aaaa    1   1   Match for id 1
1   2   aaab    1   2   Second match for id 1
1   4   aaaac   1   4   Match for id 1
```

The start of the query is the same as before. However, now there is an additional `WHERE` clause. The subquery following that basically will give back and id for which a combination of id and type in #table2 does not have a matching record in #table1.

If you were to run that subquery by itself, it would return ids 2 and 4 (4 only exists in #Table2, where id = 2, type = 3 is not in #table1.

Comment: thanks ... but will that work if in Table 1 i have id = 12 with type ="foo" and the same id =12 with type ="boo", but Table 2 have id = 12 with type ="foo" only ... will this exclude this id ? i want to see only id's that much exact combination in both tables ... hopefully that makes sense

Comment: It would not. It would show you the row of ID 12 with 'foo', but not the row with 'boo'. If you only want to show ID = 12 if it has both 'foo' and 'boo' in both tables, this would not work. The main complexity with that is that there is an infinite number of types, meaning you would have to build logic to deal with checking every possible combination. If this is what you are after, though, you might want to revisit your database design somehow.

Comment: Actually there is limited number of types, five of them. A,B,C,D,E ... Is there a way to achive the desirable outcome ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and  thorough explanation !

Comment: @user2017716 - If the reply was helpful, please consider marking it as an answer, so future visitors to the question can see what helped you solve the issue :)